# How do I set the DataContext of a ContextMenu defined in TreeView style

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview, contextmenu, menuitem

I have a TreeView which has its ContextMenu defined within a Style. The MenuItems have commands bound to them but I am having trouble binding these commands. I realise that is because the ContextMenu does not exist in the visual tree, so I have tried using the PlacementTarget object and Tag property which I have seen used in other examples but it is still not working. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong.

```
<Grid Name="MyGrid" DataContext="{Binding}">
    <TreeView Name="TreeView"
        ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewElements}"
        Tag="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=MyGrid}">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}">
                            <MenuItem Header="Do Something" 
                                      Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubElements}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding HeaderText}" ></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

**Update**

The answers below are both perfectly valid and correct but after some reflection I realised that I was looking at this problem the wrong way round. I had a look a [this article by Josh Smith](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode) where he explains that using a ViewModel pattern means you use the TreeView to **show data** and not to **put data**. As a result I was able to treat each item in the TreeView as it's own view model. This meant I could execute any command from my context menu against the specific ViewModel (and navigate up to the parent view model if required using a parent property on my new ViewModel).

Comment: The `ItemContainerStyle` is applied to a `ContentPresenter` that wraps each item, and I don't believe the `Tag` property is set of that `ContentPresenter`. Try binding the `Tag` property using another `Style` setter in your `ItemContainerStyle`.

Comment: Rachel, that worked as per #dev hedgehog 's code below. In my follow up comment do you know how I can still access the datacontext of the MenuItem I've right clicked on, as I need this for the visbility of the MenuItem

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Assuming you have bound the `Tag` property to the current `TreeViewItem` data context, you should have access to both the `DoSomethingCommand` and the property to determine visibility.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't explain that very well. The command is bound to the underlying viewModel (not the treeView) as per the 1st XML example that #devhedgehog supplied. So that means I've lost the datacontext of TreeViewItem which I've just right-clicked on. I need this so I can set the visibility on the MenuItem.

Comment: I see now. You should be able to do two separate bindings. Perhaps bind the `ContextMenu.DataContext` to the `PlacementTarget.DataContext`, and bind the `Command` to `PlacementTarget.Tag.DoSomethingCommand`. You might need a `RelativeSource` binding with that 2nd one to target `ContextMenu.PlacementTarget.Tag`

Comment: your "update" section is worth of putting as an "answer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ContextMenu does have the DataContext. You do not need to set it explicitly.

In your case the DataContext in ContextMenu is the same as for TreeViewItem. That means it is not the ViewModel but instead the item itself.

Lets say you have a list of object of type Person. Then the command should be placed inside Person.

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; this.OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    public ICommand DoSomethingCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(x => MessageBox.Show("Works!"));
        }
    }

    ...
```

And then XAML should look like this:

```
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Do Something" 
                                  Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

However if you have the command inside your ViewModel then you will need to provide the instance of ViewModel to DataContext of ContextMenu.

Here is an example:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> employee;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.Employee = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        this.Employee.Add(new Person { Name = "Test" });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Employee
    {
        get { return this.employee; }
        set { this.employee = value; this.OnPropertyChanged("Employee"); }
    }

    public ICommand DoSomethingCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(x => MessageBox.Show("Works!"));
        }
    }

    ...
```

Then the XAML would look like this:

```
    <TreeView x:Name="treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Employee}">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}, Path=DataContext}"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                            <MenuItem Header="Do Something" 
                                  Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TreeView>
```

Or the XAML could look like this:

```
    <TreeView x:Name="treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Employee}">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu DataContext="{x:Reference treeView}">
                            <MenuItem Header="Do Something" 
                                  Command="{Binding DataContext.DoSomethingCommand}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: Great that worked, I just had to move the Tag from the <TreeView /> into the Setter Property - thanks.

Comment: OK, just realised that now I can't bind the visibilty of my MenuItem because I have changed the datacontext. How should I get the DataContext of the MenuItem in this case?

Comment: You will have to consider changing the source in binding to either ViewModel or item itself.